# How to set an object as a state variable?

Tags: reactjs

I have an object called configs and I am trying to store it in a state var called stateConfig,

```
  const [stateConfig, setStateConfig] = useState(configs)
```

However when I log configs it returns as undefined. But when I log my config object variable it logs fine...Am I setting the state for the object incorrectly?

```
 const [stateConfig, setStateConfig] = useState(configs)


  //returns undefined
  console.log(stateConfig);

  //returns configs object
  console.log(configs);


  const assetIdObject =  editCriticalObjects.filter(obj => {
    if (obj.asset_id === criticalObjectsId) {
      return obj
    }
      return assetIdObject
  })

  const configs = [
    {
      label: 'Title',
      name: 'Title',
      value:  assetIdObject.map(item => item.asset_id),
      field: SinglelineTextfield,
      uniqueIdentifier: 0,
      stateVar: criticalObjectTitle,
      setStateVar: setCriticalObjectTitle,
    },
    {
      name: 'type',
      uniqueIdentifier: 1,
      label: 'type',
      value: assetIdObject.map(item => item.type),
      field: SinglelineTextfield,
      stateVar: criticalObjectType,
      setStateVar: setCriticalObjectType,
    },
    {
      name: 'Domain',
      label: 'Domain',
      value:  assetIdObject.map(item => item.Domains),
      field: SinglelineTextfield,
      uniqueIdentifier: 2,
      stateVar: criticalObjectDomainName,
      setStateVar: setCriticalObjectDomainName,
    }
  ]
```

Comment: You decalre your configs after you console.log them, therefore the it will return undefined.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to understand hoisting in JS. What is it? Simply, it is JS default behaviour of moving declarations to the top.

In JS, `let` and `const` variables are hoisted to the top of the file (in other words - declared) but not initialized.  JS only moves the declarations to the top but not initialization. Therefore, all of the variables will be declared with `undefined` value until it reaches the part of the code where this variable is initialized with a real value. If you try to use the variable before the initialization with the real value, you will get `undefined`.

When your state tries to use your `configs` which is hoisted to the top, it sees it as `undefined` as it is not yet initialised. Because of that, you are getting `undefined`.

If you want to use `configs` in a state or anywhere else, you need to define and initialize it before the state declaration or any other code that uses `configs`. Otherwise, you will get `undefined`.

To solve your issue, you simply need to move configs initialisation up.

```js
  const configs = [
    ...
  ];

  const [stateConfig, setStateConfig] = useState(configs);

  //returns configs object
  console.log(stateConfig);

  //returns configs object
  console.log(configs);
```

As a takeaway, **always declare variables at the beginning of your scope.**

Comment: just wondering how console.log(configs) returned a object in his case

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in **2 ways**:-

#### Given IF the `config` the same `js` file:-

- **1st Way**: if you declared the `config` **inside** your `JSX Functional/Class Component`. Then it **should** be before **assignation** happened.

```js
// JSX Functional/Class Component
export const Demo = () => {
  const config = [{...something}]

  // assignation happen here
  const [stateConfig, setStateConfig] = useState(configs)

  return <h1></h2>
}
```

- **2nd Way**: if you declared your `config` **outside** your `JSX Functional/Class Component`. Then it doesn't matter where the **assignation** happen in the `JSX Functional/Class Component`

```js
// can be declared OUTSIDE & BEFORE JSX Functional/Class Component
const config = [{...something}]

// JSX Functional/Class Component
export const Demo = () => {
  // assignation happen here
  const [stateConfig, setStateConfig] = useState(configs)

  return <h1></h2>
}

// can be declared OUTSIDE & AFTER JSX Functional/Class Component
const config = [{...something}]
```